# Lab 2 Google Earth Engine - Image.select error

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am new to coding and have just started using the Google Earth Engine code editor. 
I am on Lab 2 provided by Google Earth Engine: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1NojoqhGbsBnIWE2OSwYCgMmRxeZDn7F1g3kkNuMGJ1E/edit

When in complete the practical to number 1.a.v. I get two errors.

See the complete code below:

```
var myd09 = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MYD09GA');

// Define a region of interest as a point at SFO airport.
var sfoPoint = ee.Geometry.Point(-122.3774, 37.6194);

// Center the map at that point.
Map.centerObject(sfoPoint, 16);

// Get a surface reflectance image from the MODIS MYD09GA collection.
var modisImage = ee.Image(myd09.filterDate('2011-08-28').first());

// Use these MODIS bands for red, green, blue, respectively.
var modisBands = ['sur_refl_b01', 'sur_refl_b04', 'sur_refl_b03'];

// Define visualization parameters for MODIS.
var modisVis = {bands: modisBands, min: 0, max: 3000};

// Add the MODIS image to the map.
Map.addLayer(modisImage, modisVis, 'MODIS');

// Get the scale of the data from the first band's projection:
var modisScale = 
modisImage.select('sur_refl_b01').projection().nominalScale();

print('MODIS scale:', modisScale);
```

The errors i receive are:

1) Number (Error)
Image.select: Parameter 'input' is required.
2) MODIS: Layer error: Asset is not an Image or ImageCollection.

Is anyone able to help me with the solution or point me in the right direction!

Thank you,
Harriet Wilson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you print the image (to see its information), like:

```
print(modisImage)
```

you'll see that it is *null*, so I printed out the collection:

```
print(myd09)
```

and found that the collection starts on 2016, so just change the filter Date:

```
var modisImage = ee.Image(myd09.filterDate('2016-08-11').first());
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much and good tip for figuring it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is because MODIS collection 6 ([MYD09.006](https://code.earthengine.google.com/dataset/MODIS/006/MYD09GA)) has not been completely ingested (but will be).  For the purposes of this lab, you can either use a more recent image from collection 6 (as suggested previously), or use the older collection 5 ([MYD09.005](https://code.earthengine.google.com/dataset/MODIS/MYD09GA)).  I've modified the code lab to make this clear.

Comment: Hi Nicholas, thank you so much for your response. Do you know whether they have plans in the near future to ingest it? I am looking to use it for a project.

Comment: Yes, there are plans to ingest it in the near future, for some definition of "near."

Comment: Hi Nicholas, One further question if you are able to help!  :)  I was wondering whether there is MODIS Level 1b data (MOD02) on google earth engine for calculating TOA reflectance. I cant seem to find it at all. If its not on google earth engine, maybe i should alternatively use the surface reflectance data and work backwards?                          https://modis.gsfc.nasa.gov/data/dataprod/dataproducts.php?MOD_NUMBER=02

Comment: AFAIK, EE does not currently have MOD02 or any non-gridded data.